# Can a discord.py bot mute the voice of others in a voice call?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am the owner of an Among Us Discord guild with some bots I implemented into it. When we play over on of the voice calls, sometimes people forget to mute themselves so we can hear them which often reveals valuable information.

I am trying to design a set of commands that will allow one person to easily mute everyone the voice channel. They use the command `claim "VC Name"` to claim command over the indicated voice channel, then use the command `set_mute "true/false"` to either mute or unmute everyone. The first part I have down, but I am struggling with the code of the second part that actually mutes/unmutes the voice channel members.

While reading the documentation for discord.py, I found a few options that might work, but I don't know how to execute any of them.

1. `discord.VoiceState` ([Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState)): `discord.VoiceState` has attributes `mute`, `muted`, and `self_mute`. Perhaps it is possible to modify the voice state of the member with something like `member.VoiceState.mute = True`, `member.VoiceState.muted = True` or `member.VoiceState.self_mute = True`. I'm not sure how to use this method since using the above line of code results in an `AttributeError`.
2. `discord.Member.edit` ([Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member)): `member.Member.edit` has the option to set `mute` to True. This actually sets the member to a server mute (and I can't seem to undo it), so I would rather avoid this option unless there is a solution through this method.
3. I could set a unique role that is assigned to all the members in the voice channel and the bot can set the speak permissions on command. This is the method I am using right now but I would like to use an alternative one, if it exists.

This is the code that I have right now. Under the last `if/else` statement is where I will put the solution to mute and unmute the members in the call.

```py
async def mute(ctx, setting):
    regex, claimed = re.compile(f"_VC: (Lobby [0-9])_"), False
    for role in cx.message.author.roles:
        if regex.search(role.name):
            claimed = True
            break
    if not claimed:
        await ctx.send("You have not claimed any of the game lobbies")
        return
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=regex.search(role.name).group(1))
    for member in voice_channel.members:
        if setting.lower() == 'true':
            await member.voice_state.set_to_muted()
        elif setting.lower() == 'false':
            await member.voice_state.set_to_not_muted()
```

Comment: [This discord bot](https://github.com/zahid47/MuteAll) does it through `.edit(mute=True)` and `.edit(mute=False)`.

Comment: But that does a server mute

Comment: Why would you need the bot to mute them personally?

Comment: When we’re playing Among Us, often times people forget to mute themselves so I want to add a command to my bot to force mute them but not server-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For your first option, if you look at the API references of [`discord.VoiceState.self_mute`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.self_mute), you'll see a description of this attribute:

> Indicates if the user is currently muted by their own accord.

So this means that you cannot set any value, this attribute returns `True`/`False` depending on user muted his/herself or not.

---

- For your second option, it seems the best way to do this. And yes, members who has no permission, can't undo their mute but you can unmute them from code or manually.

---

- For your third option, it's another solution but I won't suggest it while you can use `member.edit`.

---

So I guess you're trying to make 2 methods named `set_to_muted` and `set_to_unmuted` but for this, you have to edit the main python files of discord.py library. Instead of that, you can create 2 async functions that takes `member` as parameter and you can mute them by this way.

```py
async def set_to_muted(member: discord.Member):
    await member.edit(mute=True)

async def set_to_unmuted(member: discord.Member):
    await member.edit(mute=False)

@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, setting):
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='')
    if setting.lower() == 'true':    
        for member in voice_channel.members:
            await set_to_muted(member)
    elif setting.lower() == 'false':    
        for member in voice_channel.members:
            await set_to_unmuted(member)
```

Comment: Is it possible to set people to `deaf` like this?

Comment: Yes, there's also a parameter named `deafen` in [`discord.Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit).